# How can I align the image horizontally and vertically using jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.minimized').click(function(event) {
        var i_path = $(this).attr('src');
        $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div><div id="magnify"><img src="'+i_path+'"><div id="close-popup"><i></i></div></div>');
        $('#magnify').css({
            left: ($(document).width() - $('#magnify').outerWidth())/2, //its not true
            top: ($(window).height() - $('#magnify').outerHeight())/1.5 //its not true
        });
        $('#overlay, #magnify').fadeIn('fast');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#close-popup, #overlay', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#overlay, #magnify').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('#close-popup, #magnify, #overlay').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

I can't understand, what needs to be substituted in top and left.

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of the image will only be known when the image has loaded and a paint cycle occurred. So wait for that cycle to occur before adjusting the wrapper element:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => { // called just before next paint
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { // called one paint cycle later
        $('#magnify').css({
            left: ($(document).width() - $('#magnify').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('#magnify').outerHeight())/1.5
        });
    });
});
```